# CLLocationManager only reports initial value?

Tags: ios, variables, core-location

So, I have been having issues with `CLLocationManager`.  More specifically reporting the local speed variable to different sections of the implementation file. Under `didUpdateLocation` method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

{
//    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {

    _speedOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.speed];
    _longitudeOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _latitudeOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    NSLog(@"%f", currentLocation.speed);
```

All of these values are changing their labels accordingly; that is not the issue. The problem arises when I try to use `currentLocation.speed`'s value in other actions in this implementation file.

So, at the top of the file, before any actions, I type:

```
 float speedGlobal;
```

Then, back under the "`if`" statement in the "`didUpdateToLocation`" I try to set this variable equal to `currentLocation.speed`:

```
speedGlobal = currentLocation.speed;
```

After running, `speedGlobal` does not change.  It appears to only report `currentLocation.speed`'s initial value, which is usually just 0.000 m/s.  While this occurs, the label directly attached to `currentLocation.speed` (_speedOutput.text) updates accurately.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I am so unbelievably befuddled. I asked a vaguer version of this question a couple days ago so I think the extra information will be helpful.

On a side note, I am truly amazed by the responsiveness and helpfulness of this community. As I become more familiar with Objective-C I hope to be able to contribute.

Cheers.

Comment: Not explaining what you're seeing but: CLLocationManager already has a `location` property that you can access outside the delegate method to get the last known location info (including speed).  You'd just have to make sure it's not nil before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you change your global variables to properties -

in your .h file

```
@property float speed;
```

and then use

```
self.speed=currentLocation.speed;
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and I'm still having the same issue :(.  I'm not sure what would be causing it not to update.

Comment: I suggest you use some breakpoints in the debugger to try and see what is going on.  Check that where you set the text of the label that you have the right value and the right object instance. A common cause of the problems you are describing is two instances of an object.